# Changing keys in dictionary

Tags: python, datetime, dictionary, key

How can I change the keys of a dictionary of lists to display dates (outright) rather than `datetime.date(2017, 1, 1)` which is what they currently are formatted as?

Example of section of list:

```
{datetime.date(2017, 9, 7): [162.3, 163.24, 162.22, 163.18], datetime.date(2017, 7, 10): [160.44, 161.13, 160.44, 160.94],
```

I am rather new to python so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Inherit `dict` and override its `__repr__` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call the `strftime` method for each datetime object:

```
import datetime
s = {datetime.date(2017, 9, 7): [162.3, 163.24, 162.22, 163.18], datetime.date(2017, 7, 10): [160.44, 161.13, 160.44, 160.94]}
new_s = {a.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"):b for a, b in s.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'2017-07-10': [160.44, 161.13, 160.44, 160.94], '2017-09-07': [162.3, 163.24, 162.22, 163.18]}
```

Comment: That changes the dictionary, while OP's problem is one of display.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ no, the OP clearly states that he wants to "change the keys of a dictionary".

Comment: Hmm, quite ambiguous. Okay, your call.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks for such a prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import datetime
my_dict = {datetime.date(2017, 9, 7): [162.3, 163.24, 162.22, 163.18], datetime.date(2017, 7, 10): [160.44, 161.13, 160.44, 160.94]}
new_dict = {str(k): v for k,v in my_dict.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'2017-07-10': [160.44, 161.13, 160.44, 160.94],
 '2017-09-07': [162.3, 163.24, 162.22, 163.18]}
```